# How to select different format types in document picker?

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

- I want to select specific document in iCloud document picker.
- But When i write more than 7 format types it'd given me error.
- Error : expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time
  consider breaking up the expression

  [ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezJiC.png)

I have done code like this :

```
let type = [String(kUTTypePDF), String(kUTTypeImage), String(kUTTypeMovie), String(kUTTypeVideo), String(kUTTypePlainText), String(kUTTypeMP3), String(kUTTypeAudio)]
let fileDocumentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: type, inMode: .Import)
fileDocumentPicker.delegate = self
self.presentViewController(fileDocumentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: "When i write more than 7 format types it'd given me error" What error?

Comment: Error : "expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time consider breaking up the expression.."

Comment: Try `kUTTypePDF as String` instead of `String(kUTTypePDF)` (for each of them)? Else, construct `type` one by one and use `append()`.

Comment: `kUTTypePDF as String` is worked. Thanks for help @Larme